# Django: How to create a Customized Reference code for each Order?

Tags: python, django, django-views

I have an E-commerce project and I am trying facilitate reading order reference codes for me, so currently I am generating random figures as following:

My current code generated is:

```
def create_ref_code():
    return ''.join(random.choices(string.ascii_lowercase + string.digits, k=6))
```

model.py

```
class Order(models.Model):
    ref_code = models.CharField(max_length=20, blank=True, null=True)
    ordered_date = models.DateTimeField()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.user.username
```

Reference code is generated every time a payment is executed:

```
def payment_complete(request):
---------payment codes-------------
    payment.save()
    # assign the payment to order
    order_items = order.items.all()
    order_items.update(ordered=True)
    for item in order_items:
        item.save()
    order.payment = payment
    order.ordered = True
    order.ref_code = create_ref_code()
    order.save()
```

My question is how do I generate a code in the following format that includes that day, month, year, hour, minute and a digit that increases with a new transaction

DDMMYYHHMMXXX
Day, Month, Year, Hour, Minute,3 digits starting with 001 and increasing with each new order.

How can I adjust my function to reach this?

Answer (score 0):

I think this might help you. Add the corresponding imports and place the code within your function that creates the order.

```py
from datetime import datetime
from commerce.models import Order

# Get current datetime and format it (You might have to adjust the timezone)
current_datetime = datetime.now().strftime('%Y%m%d%H%M%S')

# Get the total amount of orders
orders_count = Order.objects.count()
# Get the last order stored in the db
last_order = Order.objects.last()
# Get the id of the last order stored, if there is no order in the db, save a 0
id = 0 if orders_count < 1 else last_order.id
# Creates an order with the format that you wanted
Order.objects.create(ref_code=f'{current_datetime}{id+1}')
```

Comment: I have managed to work on code to be YYDDMM but I am trying to add to the function to start from 0 and every time it is generated to increment by 1

Comment: Get the automatically generated id of the last order stored and add it to the ref code. If the table is empty, get a 0. That id is set automatically and increases every time you save an order object